# Fatal error: Class 'phpseclib\Crypt\Base'

Tags: php, phpseclib

Getting this Error in php encription what to do please help

```
Fatal error: Class 'phpseclib\Crypt\Base' not found in /usr/share/php/phpseclib/Crypt/DES.php on line 55
```

Comment: Base Class Not Included. Simple.

Comment: check openssl. is it enabled

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the master branch of phpseclib? If so you need to use an autoloader. eg. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/composer/composer/master/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassLoader.php